# Create a folder on MAC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to create folders (and files) on mac in my game in the folder provided by Unity (Application.dataPath) which leads to User/Library/Application Support/Appname

I can create the folders using a simple:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathMods))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathMods);
        }
```

The folder is created but I can't write anything inside. If I try to manually find the folder using Finder, it says I don't have access to it.

I haven't found any solution on google but it seems to be a pretty simple problem.

I have also tried to call this function with 777 but it didn't work:

```
    private static bool GrantAccess(string fullPath)
    {
        try
        {
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
            sys_chmod(fullPath, 777);
#else
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
            dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
#endif
        }
        catch (PlatformNotSupportedException e)
        {
            try
            {
                sys_chmod(fullPath, 777);
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.Monitoring.Exception(e2,  LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.MethodInfoHelper.GetCurrentMethod());
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.Monitoring.Exception(e, LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.MethodInfoHelper.GetCurrentMethod());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "chmod", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int sys_chmod(string path, uint mode);
```

But it doesn't work.

To be complete all the folders don't have the same permissions for some reasons.

Comment: What are the permissions? i.e. `ls -l {dirname}` and if there are extended attributes, what does `xattr -l {dirname}` report?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My folder has dr----x--t. Couldn't make xattr work though, it doesn't show anything

Comment: So the owner access is read, sticky bit is set, and group access is execute. So your user does not have execute access.

Comment: How could I add it then ? I don't get any exception on my call to chmod but it doesn't seem to do anything. And I can't find any article about permissions on the internet

Comment: can you try Mono.Posix library to chmod?